# "grouped/clustered" regions in vector in R/python

Tags: python, r

I struggle a bit with following problem. I would like to find "grouped/clustered" regions with 1s based on following criteria:

Starting with position of first 1, if in window after 1 (for example window length==5)  there are no other 1s then start and end for output is position of 1.

1. There are no other 1s in window after.

   0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

start <- 6

end <- 6

However, if there are 1s I would like to slide window by 1 till the point there are no 1s anymore in the final widow. In that case start would be position of start of sliding and end would be position of last 1 that region.

2. There are other 1s in window after.

0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

start <- 6

end <- 16

I have many vectors like this with random distribution of 1s (apart from first position which is always 1). Below I provided example vector and preferred output. I would prefer solution for that problem in R (but python would be fine too). I would really appreciate your help.

Here is example based on window length == 5:

vector of numbers:

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1

(positions of 1s: 1  15  62  63  67  86 252 272 334 335 337 344 348 349 350 357 360 361 362 363 365 367 371 373 391 396 406 410 412)

Output:

start <- 1 15 62 86 252 272 334 344 357 391 406

end <- 1 15 67 86 252 272 337 350 373 396 412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by run length encoding the vector:

```
x <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
       0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
       0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
       1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,
       1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
       0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1)

which(x == 1)
#[1]   1  15  62  63  67  88  89  91  98 102 103 104 111 114 115 116 117 119 121 125 127 145 150 160 164 166

window <- 5

#run length encoding
y <- rle(x)
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:37] 1 13 1 46 2 3 1 20 2 1 ...
#  values : num [1:37] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 ...

#if run length for zeros is smaller than window replace with 1
y$values[(y$values == 0) & (y$lengths < window)] <- 1

#combine runs of ones
y <- rle(inverse.rle(y))

start <- cumsum(y$lengths)[y$values == 1] - y$lengths[y$values == 1] + 1
#[1]   1  15  62  88  98 111 145 160
end <- cumsum(y$lengths)[y$values == 1]
#[1]   1  15  67  91 104 127 150 166
```